# Template.destroyed() not called

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm displaying a timer showing the elapsed time since a collection item was created. However, when I navigate between Items (switch routes/url) the timer doesn't get destroyed and I end up having a bunch of leaked timers.

I could keep a reference to the timer and kill it in the router but I would prefer a cleaner way and handle it in the template. Any ideas?

```
<template name="itemDetails">
    {{elapsedTime}}
</template>

Template.itemDetails.onRendered = function() {
    var startTime = Template.currentData().startTime;
    this.timeElapsed = new ReactiveVar;

    this.taskTimer = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
        var timeElapsedInMS = Date.now() - startTime;    
        var date = new Date(timeElapsedInMS);
        var hours = (date.getUTCHours() < 10 ? '0' :'') + date.getUTCHours();
        var minutes = (date.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0' :'') + date.getUTCMinutes();
        var seconds = (date.getUTCSeconds() < 10 ? '0' :'') + date.getUTCSeconds();

        var timeElapsed = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        this.timeElapsed.set(timeElapsed);
        console.log(timeElapsed);
    }, 1000);
}

Template.itemDetails.helpers({
 elapsedTime: function() {
    return Template.timeElapsed.get();
}
});

Template.itemDetails.onDestroyed = function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(this.taskTimer);
}
```

Comment: The function to use is 'onDestroyed', not 'destroyed'. When you say navigate, do you mean another page? If the html is not re-rendered, it is not considered 'destroyed', therefore the code within 'onDestroyed' will not get invoked. Refer to the documentation at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed

Comment: So I'd have to keep a global reference to the timer and kill it in the router?

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this (template level) as well. Here is a quick example of how you could do a timer at template level:

```
<template name="test">
    <p>Count: {{time}}</p>
</template>

Template.test.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.time = new ReactiveVar(0);

    self.taskTimer = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
        self.time.set(self.time.get() + 1)
    }, 1000);
});

Template.test.onDestroyed(function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(this.taskTimer);
});

Template.test.helpers({
    time: function() {
        var self = Template.instance();
        return self.time.get();
    }
});
```

I hope you can continue from here =)